# Heroku, Code=10 Status=503

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy my ruby on rails project to heroku and i am having the following problems.

> 2019-03-30T19:36:08.379480+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-oasis-71818.herokuapp.com request_id=4b489233-5a04-4d46-b7fc-50e996636200 fwd="104.32.24.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2019-03-30T19:36:09.462696+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-oasis-71818.herokuapp.com request_id=61b24e39-429a-40fe-9e20-92b7fd29bf5e fwd="104.32.24.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2019-03-30T19:36:38.447500+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-oasis-71818.herokuapp.com request_id=01c3bf37-301a-4366-aa01-08ec922d81dd fwd="104.32.24.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2019-03-30T19:36:39.209352+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-oasis-71818.herokuapp.com request_id=351401c9-e020-4232-8bb4-4b1275e303a5 fwd="104.32.24.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Do you know what is causing these issues?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. As the log says, your **app crashed**. Without knowing what your app does, it's impossible to tell you why it crashed. Consider editing your question to provide more information.

Comment: The answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14322989/7246614) might help you.